# Adobe XMP SDK & UTF-8 strings

Tags: c++, utf-8, sdk, adobe, xmp

I am using the latest Adobe XMP SDK code from GitHub in a C++ app to read/dump the XMP data in a JPG which contains tags with UTF-8 strings - Compiled with MSVC 2019 for 64-bits static linking.

It looks like the GitHub issues page is not active.

My code:

```
SXMPMeta xmpObj;
try {
    xmpObj.ParseFromBuffer ( xmlString.c_str(), (XMP_StringLen)length );
} catch ( ... ) {
```

This code calls a callback function for output and the strings passed to the callback fail when the string contains UTF-8 code.

The string ought to be:

```xml
<photoshop:State>Baden-Württemberg</photoshop:State>
```

while the output from the callback is:

```
photoshop:State = "Baden-WürttembergC3BC>rttemberg"
                                    ===============
```

Where the UTF-8 string seems to confuse the code to not recognize the string end properly.

There seems to be some options which might control the handling of UTF-8 strings, but I have not been able to find any description or usage information regarding these.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], especially showing the actual code for the callback. For instance, what you have shown for the output is what I might expect to happen if you are reaching beyond the end of the string provided, ie if it is not null-terminated but you are treating it as if it were. Since you are parsing a memory buffer, the string passed to the callback may be just a pointer into that buffer.  Does the callback also give you the string's actual length?

Answer (score -1):

Understood, however to extract a reproducible example code would likely
be as time-consuming as tracing into the SDK code and analyzing the code
and fixing it.
My main reason for asking here was to see if anyone else had run into
a similar issue, particularly since the GitHub project seem abandoned -
there have been several issues posted, but no answers or comments for
more than a year. Apparently no one is using that SDK any longer.

To cut to the chase, I have other issues with the SDK - such as not being
able to link only the 32-bit debug version, while the 32-bit release will
link and for the 64-bit version both debug & release compile and link
cleanly.
Fortunately for me, I came across a way to get the output I need from
Exiftool. Hence this question can be closed.

Comment: "_This question can be closed_" - this website is not a bulletin board/forum and _Exiftool_ is not for programming, but instead just a program to call. Consider taking the [tour] again.